# Reversing the byte order of 4 bytes without the Zeros C++ Using a macro

Tags: c++

I almost have this figured out but I have a simple question. The below code reverses the byte order of 2 bytes and prints the below, but there are 12 zeros after `"CDAB"`.

I am uncertain how to change the code so it only reverses 2 bytes without the extra zeros. Macros are beyond me... Does it have something to do with the size of the type of `int`?

Current Output:

```
Your Computer uses Little-Endian
Before: ABCD
After : CDAB000000000000
```

My current code:

```
// Writing Data to A file.

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

//The below code is used to reverse byte/Endian order.
#define REVERSE_BYTES(...) do for(size_t REVERSE_BYTES=0; REVERSE_BYTES<sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)>>1; ++REVERSE_BYTES)\
    ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)-1-REVERSE_BYTES],\
    ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)-1-REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[REVERSE_BYTES],\
    ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)-1-REVERSE_BYTES];\
while(0)


// Check for Endianess
int Endianess(int y)
{

    int num = 1;
    if (static_cast<unsigned char>(num) == 1)
    {
        y = 1; // Little Endian
    }
    else
    {
        y = 0; // Big Endian

    }
    return y;
}

int Reverse_Endian(unsigned long long Reverse_Byte_Order)
{
    //unsigned long long x = 0xABCDEF0123456789;
      unsigned long long x = 0xABCD;

    printf("\nBefore: %llX\n", x);
    REVERSE_BYTES(x);
    printf("After : %llX\n", x);

    return x;
}



int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    x = Endianess(x);
    if (x == 0)
    {
        cout << "Your Computer uses Big-Endian";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Your Computer uses Little-Endian ";
    }
    Reverse_Endian(x);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Apparently `printf` suppresses leading zeroes, the `before` is really `000000000000ABCD`, so the result appears to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Although you assigned `0xABCD` to `x`, this does not make `x` a two-byte integer. The size of the integer is determined by it's type `unsigned long long` (typically 64-bits/8-bytes).

So although the numerical value of `x` after your assignment is `0xABCD`, it's still is represented by 8-bytes of memory (visualized as `0x000000000000ABCD`).

`printf` needs to know the variable type/size for technical reasons, but still only prints the numerical value (only adding leading zeros as requested). `printf`, by itself, does not "hex dump" a arbitrary variable.

Pre-processor macros just preform text substitution. Preforming this subsitution manually can help understand what's going on. Start with the original:

```
#define REVERSE_BYTES(...) do for(size_t REVERSE_BYTES=0; REVERSE_BYTES<sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)>>1; ++REVERSE_BYTES)\
    ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)-1-REVERSE_BYTES],\
    ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)-1-REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[REVERSE_BYTES],\
    ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)-1-REVERSE_BYTES];\
while(0);
```

Your `REVERSE_BYTES(x);` statement is substituted using the macro. The `__VA_ARGS__` is replaced by the macro argument:

```
do for(size_t REVERSE_BYTES=0; REVERSE_BYTES<sizeof(x)>>1; ++REVERSE_BYTES)
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(x))[sizeof(x)-1-REVERSE_BYTES],
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[sizeof(x)-1-REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(x))[REVERSE_BYTES],
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(x))[sizeof(x)-1-REVERSE_BYTES];
while(0);
```

Beacuse `x` is an `unsigned long long`, we'll assume that it's 8 bytes on your machine. `sizeof(x)` should equal 8.

```
do for(size_t REVERSE_BYTES=0; REVERSE_BYTES < 4; ++REVERSE_BYTES)
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(x))[7-REVERSE_BYTES],
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[7-REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(x))[REVERSE_BYTES],
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(x))[7-REVERSE_BYTES];
while(0);
```

The for statement is wrapped in a redundant do-while loop, and consists of only one statement. Change these macro idiosyncrasies to make it fit in with the style of your code:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<4; ++i) {
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[i] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(x))[7-i];
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[7-i] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(x))[i];
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[i] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(x))[7-i];
}
```

This macro is using the [XOR swap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) to swap the bytes (starting with the first+last and moving towards the middle). We can re-write this using a temporary variable to do the same thing, but improve readability:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<4; ++i) {
    unsigned char tmp = ((unsigned char*)&(x))[7-i];
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[7-i] = ((unsigned char*)&(x))[i];
    ((unsigned char*)&(x))[i] = tmp;
}
```

Hopefully, this demonstrates better what the macro is actually doing. As we've seen the 4 and 7 are controlling the number of bytes swapped. These are derived from `sizeof(x)`. So if we want to swap fewer bytes, we just need to make `sizeof(x)` smaller.

Changing `unsigned long long x = 0xABCD` to `unsigned short x = 0xABCD` will make `sizeof(x) == 2`. This should result in only two bytes being swapped, even if you leave the macro unchanged. You could also use casting or modify the macro to accept a custom size to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much your your input. I tried your code but it says "Stack around X is corrupted"

Also. You said a long long is 16 bytes. I think you meant 16bits(8 bytes).

Thanks again.

Comment: @Cyclone: That's right, I expanded sizeof(x) incorrectly and that's what's causing your stack corruption. I'll fix the values in an edit